# Show correct position on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, locationmanager

I tried to implement Google positioning application to show users position on Google maps. I found this code on Stack Overflow, but the issue with this code is, it shows 500 meter or 1000 meter away from my correct position. Does anyone know how to fix it with exact location ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my code

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
public static final String TAG = "GoogleMapsActivity";
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;
Geocoder geocoder;
Location location;
LocationListener locationListener;
CountDownTimer locationtimer;
MapController mapController;
MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);
    initComponents();
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager == null) {
        Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                "Location Manager Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location == null)
        location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        mapController.animateTo(point, new Message());
        mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
    }
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
            location = l;
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0) {
            } else {
                double lat = l.getLatitude();
                double lng = l.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(GoogleMapsActivity.this,
                        "Location Are" + lat + ":" + lng,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
    locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (location != null)
                locationtimer.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (location == null) {
            }
        }
    };
    locationtimer.start();
}

public MapView getMapView() {
    return this.mapView;
}

private void initComponents() {
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.googleMapview);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.pingreen);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Device or emulator?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I'm trying on device.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a MyLocationOverlay

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/index?com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html

Create and add to the maps overlays and it will position a marker exactly where the user is.

Something like

```
    MyLocationOverlay myOvly = new MyLocationOverlay( this, mapView );
    listOfOverlays.add( myOvly );
    myOvly.enableMyLocation();
```

To Automatically zoom to position

```
    myOvly.runOnFirstFix( new Runnable()
            { 
             public void run()
             { 
               mapController.animateTo( myOvly.getLocation() );
             }
            } );
```